# Rendering the same bibliography database in different styles

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to put together an example document (more like [the one here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html), for some kind of official decision, I will not bore you with the details) which shows how the references change with the change of bibliography styles. I planned to use the same bibliography database which will be rendered again and again in different styles.

My minimal working example is something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}

\begin{document}

\section{ACM Format}
\newbibliography{ACM}
We can cite an article in journal~\cite{ACM}{artjournal}

\bibliographystyle{ACM}{acm}
\bibliography{ACM}{mybibdb}{References}


\section{IEEE Format}

\newbibliography{IEEE}
We can cite an article in journal~\cite{IEEE}{artjournal}

\bibliographystyle{IEEE}{ieeetr}
\bibliography{IEEE}{mybibdb}{References}

\end{document}
```

---

And here is, `mybibdb.bib`.

```
@Article{artjournal,
  author =   {Author Name},
  title =    {Article name in Journal},
  journal =      {Journal Name},
  year =     {2012}
}
```

---

The problem is, when compiled, I get the multiply defined label message for `artjournal`. And this is something I can not simply ignore since the reference numbers assigned will come out to be incorrect when I add more references.

Is there any way to use the same database again and again without going through 
the painstaking process of making the keys different for multiple similar entries in the bib file? (Or using several standalone main files?)

**Complete Bunch After Solution**

The complete *(non MWE)* bunch of my working files (with the [excellent solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173416/14103) incorporated) can found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/stackexchangefilesforothers/home/CASRreferenceformat.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) for those who may need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## UPDATED

I think that this does (now!) exactly what you want. Basically, what it does is ensure that a unique label gets "attached" to each individual citation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{artjournal,
  author =   {Author Name},
  title =    {Article name in Journal},
  journal =  {Journal Name},
  year =     {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{multibbl}
\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2#3{%
\let\@citea\@empty
\@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#3\do
{\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
\edef\@citeb{\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
\@ifundefined{#2@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
\write\csname #2@auxfile\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}}%
\@ifundefined{b@#2\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
\G@refundefinedtrue
\@latex@warning
{Citation ‘\@citeb’ on page \thepage \space undefined for style #2 }}%
{\hbox{\csname b@#2\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}

\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{\bibtype#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}

\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{\item[\@biblabel{#1}\hfill]\if@filesw
  {\let\protect\noexpand
   \immediate
   \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{\bibtype#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}

 \def\bibliography#1#2#3{%
 \@ifundefined{#1@auxfile}{}{\expandafter\immediate%
 \write\csname #1@auxfile\endcsname{\string\bibdata{#2}}}%
 \def\bibname{#3}%
 \def\refname{#3}%
 \def\bibtype{#1}%
 \@input@{#1.bbl}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{ACM Format}
\newbibliography{ACM}
We can cite an article in journal~\cite{ACM}{artjournal}


\bibliographystyle{ACM}{acm}
\bibliography{ACM}{\jobname}{References}


\section{IEEE Format}

\newbibliography{IEEE}
We can cite an article in journal~\cite{IEEE}{artjournal}

\bibliographystyle{IEEE}{ieeetr}
\bibliography{IEEE}{\jobname}{References}

\end{document}
```

A few brief comments, so it's not just opaque code:

1. The essential key to this is the redefinition of the way labels are used.
2. Generally `\bibcite{x}`, which gets read in with the `bbl` file defines a label `b@<key>` which was your problem. We redefine two internal commands `\@bibitem` and `\@lbibitem` so that (instead) the label gets the form `b@<bibtype><key>` where  is the "key" for the **bibliography** being used at that point.
3. We patch `\bibliography...` so that it resets the `\bibtype`, so that the labels which get defined within it are unique.
4. We patch `\citex` so that the labels it uses are based on the particular `.aux` file that is being used for that citation.

This produces the following:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I can not say I did not think of appending the keys in the .bib file, and make the calls use the keys with the aid of some kind of macro. I am still looking for a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Yes. Updated. I think this now actually does what you want!

Comment: Works like a charm. I am also uploading my complete bunch as indicated in my question.